# Why is AjaxForm in jQuery UI Dialog accumulating posts?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, modal-dialog

I have a AjaxForm in a modalDialog that is accumulating posts. The first time it posts OK, then the second time it posts twice, then posts three times and so on...

I have found several people with the same problem, but none of their solutions worked for me. The click event and the GET are always called once, but the POST and success function are called several times.

This is my form in a partial view:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "handleModalSubmit"})) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @*FORM FIELDS*@
        <p>
            <input type="submit" class="medium buttons" value="Save" />
        </p>
}
```

On the main view this is how it (supposed to) works:

```
<div id="modal"></div>

<script>
    var linkObj;

    $('#modal').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Ordem',
        modal: true,
        width: 800,
        resizable: false
    });

    $('.showModal').click(function (e) {
        linkObj = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $('#modal').html('');
                $('#modal').html(result).dialog('open');
            }
        });
        //e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    });

    function handleModalSubmit(result) {

        if (result.value) {
            $(result.tabelaID).dataTable().fnAddData(result.linha);

            $('#modal').dialog('close');
            //$('#modal').dialog('destroy');

        } else {
            // validation failed => refresh the modal to display the errors
            $('#modal').html('');
            $('#modal').html(result);
        }
    }
</script>
```

And the controller:

```
public ActionResult AddLine()
{
    //Add some stuff to ViewBag
    return PartialView();
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddLine(Fatura fatura)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Faturas.Add(fatura);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new
        {
            value = true,
            tabelaID = "idx",
            linha = new object[] {"1", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
        });
    }
    //Add some stuff to ViewBag
    return PartialView(fatura);
}
```

Why am I getting repeated posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong. I was loading JqueryVal on the partial view of the modal. Change it to the main view and it worked.